# I can't find the error VB

Tags: vb.net

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXGub.png)
The problem appears when I try to add new bill.

The message says:

> conversion from string "4/20/2017" to type 'date' in not valid. at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.conversions.ToDate(string value)

The problem in the line 1054 `Dim duedate` as `String = DateAdd("d", +10, CDate(GetLastDayOfMonth))` and in line 1102 `<pre>set_CutoffDates`

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17P3b.png)

```
    Private Sub set_CutoffDates()
        sqlstring = "SELECT " &
            "       * " &
            "   FROM " &
            "       tblBillingProcess "

        read_record(sqlstring, "tblBillingProcess")
        txtDate.Text = Date.Now.ToShortDateString

        ' check if first billing get the last month's dates
        If ds.Tables("tblBillingProcess").Rows.Count = 0 Then

            'Dim datenow As Date = Now.Date
            'Dim Prev_Month As String = Month(DateAdd("m", -1, datenow))
            'Dim Prev_Year As String = Year(DateAdd("m", -1, datenow))
            'Dim firstdayprevmonth As String = Prev_Month & "/01/" & Prev_Year
            'Dim GetLastDayOfMonth As String = DateSerial(CInt(Prev_Year), CInt(Prev_Month) + 1, 0)
            'txtFrom.Text = firstdayprevmonth
            'txtTo.Text = GetLastDayOfMonth

            Dim datenow As Date = Now.Date
            Dim Prev_Month As String = Month(DateAdd("m", -1, datenow))
            Dim Prev_Year As String = Year(DateAdd("m", -1, datenow))
            'Dim firstdayprevmonth As String = Prev_Month & "/01/" & Prev_Year
            Dim periodFrom As String = Prev_Month & "/21/" & Prev_Year
            Dim NOW_Month As String = Month(datenow)
            Dim NOW_Year As String = Year(datenow)
            Dim firstdayofmonth As String = NOW_Month & "/01/" & NOW_Year
            Dim GetLastDayOfMonth As String = NOW_Month & "/20/" & NOW_Year
            'Dim duedate As String = DateAdd("d", +10, datenow)
            Dim duedate As String = DateAdd("d", +10, GetLastDayOfMonth)

            txtFrom.Text = periodFrom
            txtTo.Text = GetLastDayOfMonth
            txtDueDate.Text = duedate
        Else
            Dim datenow As Date
            'sqlstring = "SELECT " & _
            '    "       MAX(Periodfrom) as Periodfrom " & _
            '    "   FROM " & _
            '    "       tblBillingProcess "
            sqlstring = "SELECT " &
           "       MAX(Periodto) as Periodfrom " &
           "   FROM " &
           "       tblBillingProcess "

            read_record(sqlstring, "tblBillingProcessdate")
            datenow = CDate(ds.Tables("tblBillingProcessdate").Rows(0).Item("Periodfrom").ToString)
            'Dim Prev_Month As String = Month(DateAdd("m", -1, datenow))
            'Dim Prev_Year As String = Year(DateAdd("m", -1, datenow))
            Dim Prev_Month As String = Month(datenow)
            Dim Prev_Year As String = Year(datenow)
            Dim periodFrom As String = Prev_Month & "/21/" & Prev_Year
            Dim NOW_Month As String = Month(DateAdd("m", +1, datenow))
            Dim NOW_Year As String = Year(DateAdd("m", -1, datenow))
            Dim firstdayofmonth As String = NOW_Month & "/01/" & NOW_Year
            Dim GetLastDayOfMonth As String = NOW_Month & "/20/" & NOW_Year
            Dim duedate As String = DateAdd("d", +10, CDate(GetLastDayOfMonth))
            txtFrom.Text = periodFrom
            txtTo.Text = GetLastDayOfMonth
            txtDueDate.Text = duedate
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub btnadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click
        Try
            If btnadd.Text = "&Add" Then
                If Get_PendingPresentReading() = True Then
                    MsgBox("You must complete all present reading before creating new billing process ",
                                    MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Text)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                reset_controls()
                dgProcess.Rows.Clear()
                txtBillingNo.Text = String.Empty
                txtFrom.Text = String.Empty
                txtTo.Text = String.Empty
                txtDueDate.Text = String.Empty
                txtDate.Text = String.Empty
                generate_billingNO()
                load_data()
                set_CutoffDates()
                btnadd.Text = "&Save"
                btnedit.Enabled = False
                btncancel.Enabled = True
                btnMain.Enabled = False
                btnFind.Enabled = False
            Else
                If MsgBox("Are you sure to save this transaction ",
                          MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, Me.Text) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
```

Comment: What does it seem like the error message means?  Line 1054????

Answer (score 0):

The last day of the month, here is the calculation:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
var lastDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month);
```

then display it.  It will use your default culture.

```
txtDueDate.Text = lastDate.ToShortDateString();
```

If you want MM/dd/yyyy regardless of whether its an en-US computer, use this:

```
txtDueDate.Text = lastDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: The OP seems to be using a 'financial month' that starts on the 21st and ends on the 20th of the following calendar month